# wrapping non-ActiveRecord actions in an ActiveRecord transaction, will this work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, transactions

I have a piece of code that creates db records, but also processes a Dwolla transaction.  I want this to be all or nothing.  If any of the lines inside the transaction block throw an exception, will the first two lines (the active record lines) roll back?  Note, the whole thing is wrapped in a begin/rescue/end but I'm only concerned about this one point.

```
User.transaction do
  user.save!
  record.save!
  transactionId = Dwolla::Transactions.send({:destinationId => user.dwolla_id, :amount => amount, :pin => DwollaTransaction.get_dwolla_pin})
  transac = DwollaTransaction.create(user_id: user.id, transaction_id: transactionId, amount: amount)
end
```

Thanks for any insight.  Basically, I want to make sure that our internal records never get saved if the external API call fails.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as they're actually raising exceptions when they fail, the DB transaction will be rolled back, and your `save!`s will not be committed to the DB.